# Finding the equation of the tangent line at point P

Tags: calculus

Find an equation of the tangent line, at the point with coordinates (2,1), to the curve described by $2x^2y+xy^3-3x=4$

I'm not too sure how to solve for this question as I can't find anything in my textbook about it. I realize I need to find the derivative of the curve, which would be the following I believe, and after that I am lost.

$$4xy + y^3 - 3= 0$$

Comment: What you need is "implicit derivative" -- try finding it in the index of your text, if not google it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the $\,\def\dd{{\rm d}} \dd\,$ operator, which satisfies the following rules:

- $\dd(c)=0,\,$ if $c$ is a constant.
- $\dd(c\cdot f+g)=c\cdot\dd f+\dd g$
- $\dd(f\cdot g)=\dd f\cdot g+f\cdot \dd g$

So that, for example $\dd(x^2)= \dd x\cdot x + x\cdot\dd x=2x\,\dd x$.

Thus, we get 
$$4xy\,\dd x+2x^2\dd y + y^3\dd x+3xy^2\dd y -3\dd x = 0 \,.$$
Now we can express $\displaystyle\frac{\dd y}{\dd x}$ and substitute the given coordinates in the given expression to obtain the slope of the tangent. (You should also check that the given point lies in the curve at all..)

Answer (score 1):

Do a Taylor series expansion of the curve about $(2, 1)$ and preserve only those terms linear in $x$ and $y$ and lower. Let $f(x,y) \equiv 2x^2y + xy^3 - 3x - 4 = 0$. Then the tangent line is given by:
$$
f(x, y) = f(2, 1) + (x-2)\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)_{(2,1)} + (y-1)\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)_{(2,1)} = 0
$$
 This is the equation of the tangent line. It should simplify to:
$$
6(x-2) + 10(y-1) = 0
$$